# Altering the state of a ReactJS class after render from an outside function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In learning some reactjs and trying to keep and eye on structure (also seeing where I can go with reactjs).. I am trying to keep with a std JavaScript namespacing I know...

I have the following which renders the initial message perfectly, however the `reactTestjsx.hello.randomMsgChange();` throws an error when trying to set the state of the react class that has already been created.

Is it possible to access a react rendered class in this way?

```
//general js stuff
var reactTest = {
    toolbox: {
        shuffle: function(o){
            for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
            return o;
        }
    }
};

//JSX components
var reactTestjsx = {};
reactTestjsx.hello ={
    init: function(){
        reactTestjsx.hello.randomMsgChange();
    },

    randomMsgChange: function(){
        setInterval(function(){
            var msg = reactTest.toolbox.shuffle([
                'hello world',
                'hello solar system',
                'hello universe'
            ])[0];

            //issue here, cannot access the setState of the  "reactTestjsx.hello.show" object
            reactTestjsx.hello.show.setState( msg );
        },1000)
    },

    show : React.createClass({
        getInitialState: function(){
            return {message:'hi world'}
        },
        render: function() {
            return (
                <p>{this.state.message}</p>
            )
        }
    })
};

//render the component
React.render(
    <reactTestjsx.hello.show/>,
    document.querySelector('#content')
);
//call the init to auto switch the message
reactTestjsx.hello.init();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've taken your code and restructured it just a little bit in order to demonstrate one way to make your code work.

http://jsfiddle.net/wiredprairie/7o2sy3k5/

Here are the things I've done:

- As it would be common to use Title case for namespaces in JavaScript (and for React components), I've made that change.
- I've added an additional namespace for `Components` and placed `ShowMessage` component there
- As ReactJS is virtual DOM and "diff" oriented, I've updated the `randomMsgChange` code to rerender the `ShowMessage` control every time the `msg` has been updated.
- I've changed from using `setState` to just using normal properties as the `ShowMessage` component isn't modifying the value of the property being passed.
- When you're using JSX, syntax like: `<ShowMessage msg="Yes!"/>` is actually creating a wrapper instance of a class called `ReactElement`. That class is responsible for creating an instance of the class you've specified (such as `ShowMessage`). So, to update a property of a `ShowMessage` instance, you'll rerender the `ShowMessage`.

Code:

```
//general js stuff
var ReactTest = {
    Toolbox: {
        shuffle: function(o){
            for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
            return o;
        }
    }
};

//JSX components
var ReactTestJsx = ReactTestJsx || {};

ReactTestJsx.Hello = {
    init: function(){
        ReactTestJsx.Hello.randomMsgChange();
    },

    renderComponent: function(msg) {
        //render the component
        React.render(
            <ReactTestJsx.Components.ShowMessage message={ msg } />, document.querySelector('#content')
        );                
    },

    randomMsgChange: function(){
        setInterval(function(){
            var msg = ReactTest.Toolbox.shuffle([
                'hello world',
                'hello solar system',
                'hello universe'
            ])[0];
            ReactTestJsx.Hello.renderComponent(msg);
        },1000)
    }
};

ReactTestJsx.Components = {
   ShowMessage : React.createClass({
        getDefaultProps: function() {
           return { message: "hi world" };
        },
        render: function() {
            return (
                <p>{this.props.message}</p>
            )
        }
    })
};

ReactTestJsx.Hello.renderComponent();
//call the init to auto switch the message
ReactTestJsx.Hello.init();
```

Comment: Ahh i see i see.. so setting the state can only be done within the component class itself, access from the outside must re-render the component completely. Thank you very much, much appreciated.